# "Lost connection to MySQL server during query" kills Windows Service

Tags: mysql, delphi

I have developed a windows service using Delphi 2007.  It connects to a remote MySql database via the internet using TAdoConnection and TAdoQuery.  I have retained the default value of 30 seconds for **CommandTimeout** property.  I also create the connection/query objects on each new query and free them when done (i.e. I don't create the database connection at startup and keep it open).

Every once in a while the service stops and the event viewer shows "Lost connection to MySQL server during query".  I have everything wrapped in exceptions.  My suspicion is that there is a drop in the network while the query is executing.

Anyone have any resolution/ideas?

What triggers windows to shutdown the service?

Also, I have the service "**Recovery**" set to restart the service but this never happens.

My next step will be to start logging when each query starts and compare this to the date/time of the shutdown.  Because as of now I don't know how log this is.

Comment: You need to log each query and add a global exception handler, also with logging.

Answer (score 0):

This is may be not a direct answer, but I had same problem few days ago, and I have the mysql on local server, and I connect using [Mydac](http://www.devart.com/mydac) components.

After many tries, I found the problem came from one table that has BLOB fields, I tried to query on the table like

> select * from table

And I got this problem after the query fetch around 1600 rows, after few inspection I found the problem came from few records and seems they corrupted. so when I do query like

> Select * from my table where id not
>   between 1599 and 1650

I had this problem, if I removed `Not` from they query which fetch only 51 records I got the error, which means there's some records are corrupted, also I did mysqlcheck but it didn't fix the problem, and I tried some other check tools and I got same result, I didn't tried to delete these records, because I need why this problem happen, but I got busy with other things so I left the server for a while.

BTW, I used MySql Query browser for trying to do the queries, because other tools will give me the errors without showing how many records fetched before mysql instance terminated unexpectedly.

Comment: I too have come across this situation in the past.  But I am sorry to say it is not related.  This is a pretty simple table (with a memo though).  And I know this is not it because the same record is fetched over and over.